# $_SESSION is empty when calling an api rendered with React

Tags: javascript, php, session, reactjs

**Context**:
I have an api that is rendered with React. When I log in and I go to the admin page, I only want to see my own content, created by me and only me. To do so, I must check if my `$_SESSION['user_id']` matches the publisher_id in my database. The api allows the logged in user to create/delete/edit his post. The structure for the api is :

1. post.php where we create a class called Post with multiple methods ( create,edit etc ).
2. create.php , edit.php , read.php etc where we create a Post object and call the function we require for the action wanted.

The latter then is called in one of the components in React called Create.js etc which will then be rendered after being encapsulated in other components.

`$_SESSION['user_id']` is absent until after React finishes rendering all of our posts.

When I call echo $_SESSION['user_id'] right before my React container on the content.php page, the user_id will show up correctly. ( I use `session.start()` at the top of the page )

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['user_id']; // works

//Container for our React component.When calling the api inside the 
//component, $_SESSION['user_id'] is empty
echo "div id='app'></div>";


echo $_SESSION['user_id']; //works again, $_SESSION['user_id'] is the same as before
```

**Problem:**
 When React renders the content from my database, nothing will show up if in my SQL query I write "`... WHERE p.publisher_id=" . $_SESSION['user_id'] .` " ... " which means that `$_SESSION['user_id']` is not there anymore.

Any suggestions on how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the issue and a solution. Here they are:

Cause: The session variable is not availble in the call of the api. Opening a session there won't help either. The cause may be because the api .php file is never used to display any html.

The solution: Create a new class called User and give it the function get_user_id that will return the following : return json_encode($variableinwhichyousavedsession);
Then go to the react class that must do any of the 4 CRUD functions, use $.get("filename.php" , function { ... ) in componentDidMount. Make sure you use json.parse to get the session id and save it into a state. This way you can operate with the session id.

One problem I encountered is that you can only use $.post when you send some input or press a button. What I need to do is for it to be called when I load the page. If I find an alternative to that or an answer, I will edit this.

EDIT: it seems that I was doing something wrong when handling the $_SESSION in my api. I have corrected it and did the following:

```
$product->publisher_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

And that pretty much solved everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding session_start(); inside that div, or if that does not work, do define('_SESSION', $_SESSION);

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it doesn't work. The thing is, I already call session_start() at the top of my page so it will automatically be available throughout the page.